# Google App Indexing: It is required to specify the full website in host intent filter atribute?

Tags: android, android-intent, intentfilter, deep-linking, google-app-indexing

For example, if i have a website called:

```
http://www.testmycars.com
```

And i want that this html file gets indexed and display a link to my app content when someone searches for chevrolet in his android device search app:

```
http://www.testmycars.com/cars/huge/chevrolet.html
```

so i add this to head of that html file:

```
<link rel="alternate" href="android-app://com.mycompany.myapp/http/section/chevrolet"/>
```

and i add this intent filter to my android manifest:

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="http"
                android:host="section" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Will it work with that host atribute in the intent filter and that URI in the head of my html? i dont want to specify the full website because i'm using an app generator that builds a lot of apks with the same host atribute for this intent-filter. Will google app indexing works with this code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell me what is your objective. Is it to relate one web site to multiple Apps, providing the same content on all the Apps, or is it to provide a different content (different sections) from the website in each of the Apps?

Also, why don't you want to provide the full domain of the website in the deep link?

Cheers.